# Excel VBA, Null textbox, and CInt

Tags: vba, excel

What I'm trying to do is take the values from 4 textboxes and put them into 4 different sheets, but they need to be Integers so the `Average` and `Sum` functions work. But if the value is Null to clear the textbox so that value isn't calculated into the Monthly Sums or Averages. I keep getting a Type Mismatch Error with the Else clause, and when I mouse over it, it shows me `frmDataEntry.tbBloodDraws = ""`. I thought that the else clause would just take the value and change it to an Int as long as it wasn't empty or Null? What am I missing?

```
Private Sub btnOK_Click()

' Get currently selected Cell of the Data Entry Sheet
Dim DataEntryCell As String
DataEntryCell = ActiveCell.Address

'Copy values from the dialog box into the correct sheets

Worksheets("Blood Draws").Activate
Range(DataEntryCell).Select

If (IsNull(frmDataEntry.tbBloodDraws)) Then
    ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Clear
Else
    ActiveCell.Value = CInt(frmDataEntry.tbBloodDraws)
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Please try maybe `ActiveCell.Clear` alone instead of `ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Clear`

Comment: No problem :) Thanks for responding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ClearContents` to remove only the content of the cell and then check with `IsNumeric` if the string can be interpreted as number.

```
If tbBloodDraws.Text = "" Then
    ActiveCell.ClearContents
ElseIf IsNumeric(tbBloodDraws.Text) Then
    ActiveCell.value = CInt(tbBloodDraws.Text)
End If
```

Comment: Thank you Dee, that also works and in addition it clears the contents of the cell.

Comment: Yes i was afraid that the former answer was not completelly correct because IsNull(textBox) is never true. I'm glad I could help.